# mysql - get aggregate result with 2 min. range

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, mysql-workbench

I have user's activity table in my application, and I need to show aggregate 
report for 2 min. range.

```
id   datetime              userid  activity
--   -------------------   ------  --------
1    2014-27-12 02:10:57   1       'read'  
2    2014-27-12 02:10:59   1       'ok'  
3    2014-27-12 02:11:02   1       'write'  
4    2014-27-12 02:13:03   1       'write'  
5    2014-27-12 02:15:06   1       'write'  
6    2014-27-12 02:15:08   1       'ok'  
7    2014-27-12 02:17:07   1       'read'  
8    2014-27-12 02:18:01   1       'read'
9    2014-27-12 02:18:02   1       'read'    
10   2014-27-12 02:18:05   1       'read'    
11   2014-27-12 02:18:25   1       'read'    
12   2014-27-12 02:21:09   1       'read'
```

I want result in 2 minitus range as follows.

```
userid id  datetime (min)       datetime (max)       count
------ --  -------------------  -------------------  ----- 
1      1   2014-27-12 02:10:57  2014-27-12 02:11:02  3                
1      4   2014-27-12 02:13:03  2014-27-12 02:15:08  3
1      7   2014-27-12 02:17:07  2014-27-12 02:18:25  5
1     12   2014-27-12 02:21:09  2014-27-12 02:21:09  1
```

Does anyone can explain, how to Do this?

Comment: What do you mean with aggrigate? What's that?

Comment: Your second row of results is wrong, there's more than 2 minutes between `2:13:03` and `2:15:08`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT userid, min(id) AS id, 
        MIN(datetime) AS `datetime (min)`, MAX(datetime) AS `datetime (max)`,
        COUNT(*) AS count
FROM activity
GROUP BY userid, FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/120)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25b234/1)